# Pixel overflow when using an Image.File in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a column with 2 children, an Image.File and a Row displaying a Flatbutton.Icon.  The Image.File causes an overflow, but when I use Expanded on both Image.File and Row the entire body vanishes.  How do I avoid both outcomes and just show the intended which is the photo with a flatbutton below it?

Parent

```
class ProfileHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileHomeState createState() => _ProfileHomeState();
}

class _ProfileHomeState extends State<ProfileHome> {

  File _imageFile;

  Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    File selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = selected;
    });
  }

  void _clear() {
    setState(() => _imageFile = null);
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text(
            'My Profile',
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Anton'),
          ),
          centerTitle: true),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: DrawerWidget(),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          if (_imageFile == null) ...[
            ProfileList(
              uploadbarvalue: _updateUploadBar,
            ),
          ] else ...[
            ProfilePhoto(
              imageFile: _imageFile,
              onImageExit: _clear,
            )
          ]
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: (uploadbar)
          ? BottomAppBar(
              shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.photo_camera,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                      uploadbar = false;
                    },
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.photo_library,
                        size: 50.0,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                        uploadbar = false;
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            )
          : null,
      floatingActionButton: (uploadbar)
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              child: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  uploadbar = false;
                });
              })
          : null,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

Child

```
class ProfilePhoto extends StatefulWidget {
  File imageFile;
  final VoidCallback onImageExit;
  final bool uploadbar;
  final ValueChanged<bool> uploadbarvalue;
  ProfilePhoto(
      {Key key,
      this.uploadbar,
      this.uploadbarvalue,
      this.imageFile,
      this.onImageExit})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePhotoState createState() => _ProfilePhotoState();
}

class _ProfilePhotoState extends State<ProfilePhoto> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      if (widget.imageFile != null) ...[
        Image(image: FileImage(widget.imageFile)),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  _imageFinished();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                label: Text('Clear'))
          ],
        ),
        Uploader(
          file: widget.imageFile,
        )
      ]
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: added code above

Comment: Check out layout builder